# Prove $\sin^2 A = \sin^2 B \sin^2 C - 2\sin B \sin C \cos A$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I am asking for help with this proof:

Given $\triangle ABC$. Prove that $\sin^2 A = \sin^2 B+ \sin^2 C - 2\sin B \sin C  \cos A$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you learned about Law of Sines and Law of Cosines?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Let us write the Al Kashi formula:
$$a^2 = b^2 + c^2
-2bc\cos A
$$ and the sine law:$$
\frac{\sin A}a = \frac{\sin B}b = \frac{\sin C}c
$$hence:

$$
\sin^2 A = a^2\frac{\sin^2 A}{a^2}
= (b^2 + c^2-2bc\cos A)\frac{\sin^2 A}{a^2}\\
= b^2\frac {\sin^2 B}{b^2}+c^2\frac {\sin^2 C}{c^2}
- 2 bc \cos A\frac{\sin B}b \frac{\sin C}c
\\
\sin^2 A= \sin^2 B+\sin^2 C -2\sin B\sin C  \cos A
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using [Prove that $\sin^2(A) - \sin^2(B) = \sin(A + B)\sin(A -B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600681/prove-that-sin2a-sin2b-sina-b-sina-b) and $\displaystyle A+B+C=\pi\iff A+B=\pi-C,\sin(A+B)=\sin(\pi-C)=\sin C$

$$\sin^2A-\sin^2B-\sin^2C$$
$$=\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)-\sin C\sin C$$
$$=\sin(\pi-C)\sin(A-B)-\sin C\sin\{\pi-(A+B)\}$$
$$=\sin C\sin(A-B)-\sin C\sin(A+B)$$
$$=-\sin C[\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)]$$
$$=-\sin C[2\sin B\cos A]$$

Comment: @ArchytasMoon, how about this?