# Simplify a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

UPDATE **** AGGGH, I am embarrassed, but I made an error in deriving the equation in this question.  Please disregard this question, and I will start a new one if I get stuck on the corrected version.  It does appear that @avz2611's hint may still come into play though, so at least this post was not for nothing. :)  (I'm not sure how to "close" a question.)

---

I have a problem that after many manipulations was able to reduce it down to the following equation with only one unknown, $b$:

$$\sin^2(a+b) + 2 \sin(a) \cos(t) \sin(a+b) - \sin^2(b) = 0.$$

So $a$ and $t$ are known constants.  The unknown, $b$, is what I am trying to solve for if it's possible.  Is it possible to solve for $b$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600681/prove-that-sin2a-sin2b-sina-b-sina-b

Answer (score 1):

$HINT$: $sin(x+y)sin(x-y)$=$sin^2x-sin^2y$ try to find the expression and simplify

Comment: Following the hint here the equation becomes $0 = \sin(a+2b) + 2 \cos(t) \, \sin(a+b)$. The solutions of which are not easy to find and with the use of Wolfram Alfa are : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\sin%28a%2B2x%29+%2B+2+p+\sin%28a%2Bx%29+%3D+0

Comment: So I just got out of an afternoon meeting, and saw this very interesting hint with a property I was unaware.  Is the output from wolframalpha.com a solution?  The URL is mangled.

Answer (score 0):

have you try to develop $sin(a+b)$, then say $X=sin(b)$ and try to solve ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question, but I tried converting sin(a+b) to sin(a)cos(b)+sin(b)cos(a) and then expanding everything out.   I got a nice long equation, with many of the terms containing either sin(b) or cos(b) and not being able to isolate the b terms.  I'd be happy to show the expansion if it helps?

Comment: Hum yes, you are right, you'll have some trouble with cos(b).

Comment: it is difficult to solve this equation for $b$

Comment: OK.  Maybe I need to draft up the original problem that got me to that equation and see if there is an entirely different way to attack it.  I have taken many approaches and keep running into dead-ends, however the above equation is the closest I have gotten by far.