# Prove by induction: $\sin{x}+\sin{3x}+\dots+\sin{(2n-1)x}=\frac{\sin^2{nx}}{\sin{x}}$

Tags: trigonometry, induction

> Prove by induction:
>   $$\sin{x}+\sin{3x}+\dots+\sin{(2n-1)x}=\frac{\sin^2{nx}}{\sin{x}}$$

I tried the problem using the normal rule of induction(the first principle), but I failed.I failed to make the form $\sin^2{(m+1)x}$. Somebody help me.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Note that by the [product to sum property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities), we have that

$$\sin(x)\sin((2k-1)x)=\frac12\left(\cos((2k-2)x)-\cos(2kx)\right)$$
This implies that $$\sin((2k-1)x)=\frac{\frac12\left(\cos((2k-2)x)-\cos(2kx)\right)}{\sin x}$$
Use $\cos 2a=1-2 \sin^2 a$ for all $a$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 1):

You know that
$$
\sin y=\frac{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}{2i}
$$
so you have
$$
\frac{\sin^2nx}{\sin x }+\sin(2n+1)x=
\left(\frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i}\right)^2\frac{2i}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}+
\frac{e^{i(2n+1)x}-e^{-i(2n+1)x}}{2i}
$$
This becomes
$$
\frac{e^{2inx}-2+e^{-2inx}+(e^{i(2n+1)x}-e^{-i(2n+1)x})(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}
{2i(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}
$$
The numerator is
$$
e^{2inx}-2+e^{-2inx}+e^{i(2n+2)x}-e^{-2inx}-e^{2inx}+e^{-i(2n+2)x}=
(e^{i(n+1)x}-e^{-i(n+1)x})^2
$$
so finally
$$
\frac{\sin^2nx}{\sin x }+\sin(2n+1)x=
\frac{(e^{i(n+1)x}-e^{-i(n+1)x})^2}{2i(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})}=
\frac{(2i)^2\sin^2(n+1)x}{2i\cdot 2i\sin x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1$ it's obvious.

Thus, it remains to prove that $$\frac{\sin^2nx}{\sin{x}}+\sin(2n+1)x=\frac{\sin^2(n+1)x}{\sin{x}}$$ or
$$1-\cos2nx+\cos2nx-\cos(2n+2)x=1-\cos(2n+2)x,$$
which is obvious.

Comment: We can use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600681/prove-that-sin2a-sin2b-sina-b-sina-b